# in Mvc web app need to use captcha?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, captcha

I have mvc web app i need to use captcha ,
i did it like add an dll which i have got from codeplex but
at register.aspx page I have added that code like following which is giving me capcha

```
   <%: CaptchaMVC.HtmlHelpers.CaptchaHelper.Captcha(Html,"Refresh","Input Symbols",5) %>
```

and code at AccountController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NotAttribute()
        {

            if (this.IsCaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid"))
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Captcha is valid";
                return View();
            }

            TempData["Message"] = "Captcha is not valid";
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")]
        public ActionResult UseAttribute()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Captcha is valid";
                return View();
            }
            TempData["Message"] = "Captcha is not valid";
            return View();
        }
```

But in its not working properly as in debug mode too after clicking on register button it is not able to hit any one these method 
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not too late may I suggest an alternative to CAPTCHA, here is why:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/captcha-is-dead-long-live-captcha.html

if you are sold, here is a simple technique I use called the Honeypot,

you can add this to your View

```
@Html.TextBox("NameItWhateverYouWant", null, new {style="display:none"})
```

now you have a hidden field on your form, then in your controller,

```
 bool botAttack = Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("NameItWhateverYouWant")
      && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["NameItWhateverYouWant"]);
```

basically only a robot attacking your registration process would be filling this field.

did I mention that this makes for a better user experience too?

Here is the blog post that inspired the solution:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/11/honeypot-captcha.aspx

Comment: Robots can be programmed to ignore hidden fields (even if they are only hidden by css). watch out.

Comment: How do you think a regular user can fill hidden field? with FireBug?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Recaptcha for .NET (http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com) to use a robust and secure captcha solution for your MVC .NET project with just few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution and there is now a HoneyPot for ASP.NET MVC. You can find it here:

http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleHoneypot.MVC

Answer (score 0):

OK, so since SO does not allow me to post my full reply, I'll post it here...

Firstly, I don't belief that the honeypot approach is effective as it is quite easy for bots to identify which fields are hidden,as gdoron correctly pointed out.

Secondly, ReCAPTCHA is one of the most, if not the most used captcha implementation available today.  Free, open source, relatively effective against most, not all, bots (No CAPTCHA is impenetrable).  I have used some of the other .Net recaptcha implementations and MVCRecaptcha was actually the only one I had any success with - perhaps something to do with the DotNet version I was using?  Simply put, it worked for me and the others did not.